# Golang Gmail API Error 400: Bad Request, failedPrecondition

Tags: go, gmail-api

I'm attempting to send email using Gmail's API but I keep getting the error:

**Unable to send googleapi: Error 400: Bad Request, failedPrecondition
exit status 1**

I created a service account for this in the console.developers.google.com page and downloaded the private json file. Renamed it GmailService.json and searched through the docs on how to implement it. From what I can tell everything works except when it gets to the send method at the end of the code. Either the service email doesn't allow me to send email or the message is formatted wrong?

```
package main

import "golang.org/x/oauth2"
import "golang.org/x/oauth2/google"
import "google.golang.org/api/gmail/v1"
import "io/ioutil"
import "log"
import "encoding/base64"
import "strings"

func main() {

    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile("GmailService.json")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    conf, err := google.JWTConfigFromJSON(data, "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("conf: %v", err)
    }

    client := conf.Client(oauth2.NoContext)

    gmailService, err := gmail.New(client)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("gmailService: %v", err)
    }

    var message gmail.Message

    messageStr := []byte("From: service-email@gmail.com\r\n" +
        "To: recipient@gmail.com\r\n" +
        "Subject: Testing testing \r\n" +
        "\r\nThis message was created with an api")
    message.Raw = base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(messageStr)
    message.Raw = strings.Replace(message.Raw, "/", "_", -1)
    message.Raw = strings.Replace(message.Raw, "+", "-", -1)
    message.Raw = strings.Replace(message.Raw, "=", "", -1)

    _, err = gmailService.Users.Messages.Send("me", &message).Do()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to send %v", err)
    }

}
```

Comment: doesn't seem to match the hostname and paths documented at https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/#Users.messages but ofc google has a trillion API's... have you considered sending with IMAP instead?

Comment: when usin google.JWTConfigFromJSON you should use the constante defines in the gmail api (gmail.GmailSendScope in your case instead of the full link). EDIT: you're sending the message as if it were you, but have authorize your application to send e-mail by your name?